# creating sub-strings from strings without referring index

Tags: python, string, loops

suppose I have a string like

```
mystr = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTYWXYZ'
```

Suppose I want to create a substrings of 5 characters out of it, then a possible answer is

```
for i in range(len(mystr)):
    tmp = mystr[i-2:i+3];
    sub_str.append(tmp)
```

Another case is :
What if I need to create substrings for a particular condition like:

```
for i in range(len(mystr)):
    if mystr[i] == 'L':
        tmp = mystr[i-2:i+3]
        sub_str.append(tmp)
```

This is very easy, But I want another way out for it, that is I don't want to use the indexing method (like mystr[i-2:i+3]) in any form. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the conditional case, if you do not want to use a `for` loop in your code, you can use the `string.find()` method.  Your code would then look like this:

```
substr_start = my_str.find("L") - 2
substr.append(my_str[substr_start:substr_start+5])
```

Keep in mind that the `string.find` method only returns first index of the substring's occurance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `step` argument to use indexes which increment by 5, which is passed into the [`range()`](//docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) built-in function as the 3rd argument (after `start` and `stop`).

So in this case, your first `for` loop would look like:

```
for i in range(0, len(mystr), 5):
    tmp = mystr[i:i+5]            # changed from i-2:i+3
    sub_str.append(tmp)
```

For the second `for` loop, again starting at 0 and changing the slice from `[i-2:i+3]` (and updating the character index in the `if` condition to behave the same way as your original one):

for i in range(0, len(mystr), 5):
    if mystr[i + 2] == 'L':
        tmp = mystr[i:i + 5]
        sub_str.append(tmp)

I don't think it's possible to slice a string without indexing.